# GRASS error after installation

Tags: grass-gis

I have installed GRASS GIS 7.6 and when launching it, the next error shows:

```
ERROR: The APPDATA variable points to directory which does not exist, ask your operating system support
Exiting...
Press any key to continue . . .
```

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Please check out our short tour->https://gis.stackexchange.com/tour to learn about our focused Q&A format. Also as the error says the APPDATA variable points to a non existent directory. So change the variable to something that actually exists and it should work.

Comment: How exactly can I do that?

Comment: You could try reading here->https://grass.osgeo.org/grass77/manuals/variables.html

Comment: Could this be useful? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/329308/environment-variable-may-not-expand-appdata-to-the-application-folder